# How to convert the data type in numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Is there any convenient ways to convert the data type in matrix of numpy?

Comment: Something like `A = A.astype(np.uint8)`, `A = A.astype(float)`, `A = A.astype(object)`, etc, where `A` is your array?

Comment: Thank you. It helps me a lot.